# Capacitor - Geolocation does not work on iOS but works on Android

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, geolocation, capacitor

I am writing an application that uses geolocation. Everything works perfectly on the web and Android.
However, on ios, I cannot fetch location (the second method that I have implemented - pick a location from the map works though)

I am getting this error in Xcode console:

```html
⚡️  To Native ->  Geolocation getCurrentPosition 7620184
ERROR MESSAGE:  {"errorMessage":"The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(kCLErrorDomain error 0.)","message":"The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"}
```

This is my method which fetches location:

```js
 private locateUser() {
        if (!Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('Geolocation')) {
            this.showErrorAlert();
            return;
        }
        this.isLoading = true;
        Plugins.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
            .then(geoPosition => {

                const coordinates: Coordinates = {
                    lat: geoPosition.coords.latitude,
                    lng: geoPosition.coords.longitude
                };
                this.createPlace(coordinates.lat, coordinates.lng);
                this.isLoading = false;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.isLoading = false;
                this.showErrorAlert();
            });
    }
```

Do you have any idea what may cause this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. In the Simulator clicking Features > Location > Custom Location and setting a location there fixed the issue for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: I've spent a lot of time dealing with this, you have saved me, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I had set a preference tag with a host name and his ip adress in config.xml for other purposes.
Removing it solved the geolocation error